# How do i display booking details on confirmation page using mern stack

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am a beginner in programming. I am building an appointment booking system using mern stack. I have created the booking form which sends data to the database, now i  need to display the booking details ona confirmation page,which i am finding difficult. please this is where i need some help

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';





class Form extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleDateChange = this.handleDateChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);


    }
    state = {
        name: "",
        service: "finance",
        date: new Date(),
        cost: "3"
    };

    styles = {
        fontSize: 50,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        color: "blue"

    }

    //event to handle all inputs except datepicker
    handleChange(e) {

        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        //to update the input state

        this.setState({ [name]: value });

    }
//event to handle datepicker input
    handleDateChange(date) {
        //update the date state
        this.setState({
            date:date
        })
    }


    


    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        //console.log(this.state);
    if(this.state.value !== ""){
        alert('booking success')
    }
    
      
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api', this.state)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })

            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        this.setState({ name: '', service: '', date: '', cost: '' })

        
    }


    render() {
        return (

            <form className='form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h2 style={this.styles}>Create appointment</h2>
                <div className="mb-3">
                    <label className="form-label">Name</label>
                    <input name='name' type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />

                    <label className="form-label">Service</label>
                    <input name='service' type="text" className="form-control " id="exampleFormControlInput1" value={this.state.service} onChange={this.handleChange} />

                    <label className="form-label"> Date</label>
                  <div>
                  <DatePicker
                  
                  selected={this.state.date}
                  onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                  name='date'
                  />
                 
        </div>

             


                   {/* <label className="form-label"> Date</label>
                    <input name='date'type="datetime-local" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"  value={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange} />


*/}
                    <label className="form-label">Cost</label>
                    <input name='cost' type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" value={this.state.cost} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </div>
               <Link to={'/ConfirmBooking'} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-outline-success" />
    </Link>
           
            </form>

        )
    }

}
export default Form;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Form from './Form';



class ConfirmBooking extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }
  
   state = {
    
   }; 

   
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api', this.state)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })

    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
this.setState({ name: '', service: '', date: '', cost: '' })


  }

  render() { 
  
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
        <h3>Booking review</h3>
        
        </form >
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default ConfirmBooking
;
```

the first code is for the oking form which works fine. The one underneath is for displaying booking details but doesnt work. please kindly help me

Comment: you are trying to pass this.state as second argument in axios.get() method. Remove it and try again once. And watch over console developer tools what error you are getting. Also call you API call using life cycle. you are using it inside handleSubmit method which only trigger when you click button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @SujitLibi ... everything works fine now.